# Destroy function isn't functioning in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]



  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(book_id: @book.id).order("created_at DESC")

      if @reviews.blank?
        @avg_review = 0
      else
        @avg_review = @reviews.average(:rating).round(2)
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @book.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  private
    def set_book
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :language, :year, :description, :total_pages, :rating, :image)
    end

  end
```

This is my bookscontroller and my "delete" in show file is as below.

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', book, 
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete %>
```

I am getting a link, but its not working. What is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "not working"? Does `BooksController#destroy` not get called? Does `set_book` fail? Does `@book.destroy` fail? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Anything in the server logs?

Comment: you need to debug `set_book` and `authenticate_user!` filters if everything is getting assigned correctly there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put  `//= require jquery_ujs` to 
`assets/javascripts/application.js`.